Images still organized in folder with hex
I have migrated an old version of Mediawiki to 1.39.
The current problem is that the files in the image folder are organised differently than in the old version.
In the old version, the images were directly in the folder, without subfolders.
Currently (with 1.39) they are in the Hex folder
/b/B26/Image.png

Therefore, the references in the images are broken.
I have already deactivated the function with
$wgEnableHashedUploads = false;

Nothing changes
How do I get the old folder structure back? Otherwise I have to upload all images again...

I think you will need to move image files with a shell script.

To completely deactivate the creation of subfolders, set the value wgHashedUploadDirectory= false
